# Calculating the legs of a right angle triangle

Tags: triangles

Given- right angle triangle which is divided by its height, forming two triangles. The aria of one is S II=30.533(cm^2) c(hypotenuse)=65 (cm)
The legs of the triangle need to be calculated. [diagram of the triangle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6TSr.png)

Comment: HINT: double area divided by hypothenuse gives the altitude.

Comment: From the given sketch  
$ \frac12 \cdot 65 \cos^2 \alpha \cdot 65 \sin \alpha \cos \alpha =S_2$ So this allows you to calculate $\alpha$.. 
Proportion all the other sides by similar triangles of trigonometry using ratio of sides relations.

Answer (score -1):

From your given sketch
$$ \frac12 \cdot 65 \cos \alpha \cdot 65 \sin \alpha =S12$$

So this allows you to calculate $\alpha$

Proportion all the other sides by similar triangles using trigonometric ratios.